# React-Native Scrollview and FlatList's scroll conflicting with each other

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

[image] I am running into an issue and the issue is i am working with scrollview and Flat List basically i have a view in which as we can see static view on top and some tabs on the centre of the screen and i am using flat list to render the tabs data which is quite large but i want to to scroll top static profile view while i scroll Flat List so the upper profile will also scroll while scrolling Flat list for that i wraps a scrollview on the root of this view but when i scroll flat list scroll and scrollviews scroll conflicting with each other and as a result i can't scroll to bottom or top in centre of the Flat List, any suggestion about this ?

```
return (
  <ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled style={{flex: 1}}>
      <ProfileView />
      <ProfileTabView />
  </ScrollView>)
```

I want to render Flat List inside scrollview and they shouldn't make any conflict with each other while scrolling and scroll not shouldn't be stuck in the centre of Flat List.

Comment: Please share an image of the page design. A wireframe at the least will give a rough idea.

Comment: @Ron I have updated my question with adding an image.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for [react-native-scrollable-tabview](https://github.com/valdio/react-native-scrollable-tabview). Do comment if you want more guidance.

Comment: I have already implemented react-navigation tabs and also using scrollview and this working fine with array of 10 or 12 length the problem occurs when there is 50, or 60 cards in the list and list stuck while scrolling because of conflict of scrollview and Flat list scroller.

Comment: Even i faced this issue @WaheedAkhtar. The only way i could solve this is by treating `scrollview`  and  `flatlist` differently. The above package will help you solve this problem. I Request you to give it a try. I'll be posting a sample code for your reference.

Comment: I found a way to solve my problem by disabling the scroller of `Flat List` and start using the scrollview for scrolling the components of  `Flat List`.